# Unable to parse through the .pfx file using PKCS12_parse?

Tags: openssl, cryptography

Created memory store with desired certificate moved from system store to memory store and saved that store to file.

The moved certificate can be acquired by using the function

CertFindCertificateInStore() from the created memory store successfully.

The memory store is exported successfully using the function

```
bResult = PFXExportCertStoreEx(
                                        hMemoryStore,
                                        &pPFX,
                                        wszPassword,
                                        NULL,
                                        EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEYS | 
                                        REPORT_NOT_ABLE_TO_EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEY | 
                                        REPORT_NO_PRIVATE_KEY );

 BIO* input = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)pPFX.pbData, pPFX.cbData);
            p12 = d2i_PKCS12_bio(input, NULL);
            if(NULL == p12)
            {
                hResult = GetLastError();
                __leave;
            } // if

iResult = PKCS12_parse(p12, "mqroot", &pkey, &cert, NULL);
            if ( !iResult )
            {
                hResult = GetLastError();
                __leave;
            } // if
```

Here when the certificate is parsed returning 1, but the pkey and cert parameters are NULL.
What can be the reason for getting private key and certificate as NULL.

Comment: Have you initialized the `EVP_PKEY **pkey` and `X509 **cert` params beforehand? With `EVP_PKEY_new` and `X509_new` ?

Comment: After initializing EVP_PKEY *pkey and X509 *cert with EVP_PKEY_new and X509_new, it is returning NULL values for pkey and cert.

Comment: You shouldn't have to initialize them to anything but NULL prior to the invoke. And checking `GetLastError` is completely worthless where it is located, as that reports Windows API and their subsystem errors, not OpenSSL errors. That should be placed after the PFXExportCertStoreEx call, and even then only if it *fails*. Once an OpenSSL call fails, to get the actual error info you should use `ERR_get_error` and `ERR_error_string` , whose names are hopefully self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add "OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();" to your code. This will initialize some of the algorithms which are needed by PKCS12_parse. As explained in this article, https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms.html.